# Why Data Cloud transformations use WHERE Field <> "" AND Field <> ''? What kind of SQL syntax support that?

Tags: salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

Why Data Cloud transformations use `WHERE Field <> "" AND Field <> ''`? What kind of SQL syntax supports that?

If I try to do some filters like `WHERE Field <> ""` in SQL Fiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dd7ee/322
it is not accepted

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_streaming_transform_supported_functions.htm&type=5) mentions the following information:

> For the Text data type:
>
> To check for a null value, use field = ''. For the Text data type,
> null values and empty strings are different. An empty string is
> represented by a double quote "" without characters between the double
> quotes.
>
> To check for a non-null value, use field <> ''. To exclude both empty
> strings and null values, use field <> "" AND field <> ''. In Data
> Explorer, both empty strings and null values are displayed as NULL. To
> ensure accurate filtering, it’s recommended to include checks for both
> null values and empty strings.

[image]

Which basically means `<> ''` means `IS NOT NULL` and `<> ""` means `IS NOT EMPTY STRING`. So when we include both `field <> '' AND field <> ""` this basically means the field is neither `null` nor an empty string literal.

Also, looks like this is [special proprietary dialect for SQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.bi_dev_guide_sql.meta/bi_dev_guide_sql/bi_sql_select.htm) which is called `CRM Analytics SQL`
[image]
and which is highly different from MS SQL or MySQL dialect syntaxes.